# XSD - restrict the values of an element to be contained in the values defined by other element

Tags: xml, xsd

In a XSD file, how can I restrict the values of an element to be contained in the values defined by other element?
In other words, to declare a certain value, it has to be already instantiated by other element.

For instance:

I have a list of sensors,

```
<SensorDefinitionList>
  <SensorDefinition>
    <Name>ROLK8900</Name>
    <DisplayName>TRM1</DisplayName>
    <Presence>YES</Presence>
    <SensorId>40</SensorId>
    <Coordinates>0,0</Coordinates>
  </SensorDefinition>
  <SensorDefinition>
    <Name>JBLK7200</Name>
    <DisplayName>JBLK</DisplayName>
    <Presence>YES</Presence>
    <SensorId>35</SensorId>
    <Coordinates>0,0</Coordinates>
  </SensorDefinition>
  ...
</SensorDefinitionList>
```

and an element containing their distribution, for example:

```
<SensorDistributionList>
  <SensorDistribution>
    <SensorDistributionId>0</SensorDistributionId>
    <Name>System</Name>
    <ListOfSensor>SDF</ListOfSensor>
  </SensorDistribution>
  <SensorDistribution>
    <SensorDistributionId>3</SensorDistributionId>
    <Name>MLAT</Name>
    <ListOfSensor>MLAT</ListOfSensor>
  </SensorDistribution>
  ...
</SensorDistributionList>
```

In the XSD, I want to assure that the SensorDistribution name that I am describing is a sensor name previously defined in the SensorDefinition.
How can I write my XSD in such manner?

```
...
<xs:element name="SensorDistributionList">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SensorDistribution">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SensorDistributionId" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="ListOfSensor" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the name of `SensorDefinition` as `xs:ID` and use it in `SensorDistribution`.

```
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SensorDefinition">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            ...
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:ID" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SensorDistribution">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            ...
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:IDREF" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

More:
More:

- [xsd tutorial on my blog](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/xsd-tutorial.html)
- [xsd problem list on my blog](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/xsd-tutorial-2-problem-lists.html)